# matches listing changes to most recent after selecting one job - please cookie it

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

By searching for a job you have two tabs, have you, one that says **matches** and another that says **most recent**.  After I've used the feature to match for specific jobs by entering my likes / dislikes and compensation I am presented with matches.  Great I see a few I like...

I start by clicking my first potential opportunity, read over it and sort of like it but I'd like to read about some of the other opportunities.  So what do I do, I click the "search results" link at the top of this company page.  I expect to see those some results (the matches tab) but instead my query is destroyed and the focus has been changed to **most recent**.

The tab you are looking at should be cookied / sessioned to maintain its state at least during the session I would say.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deployed the fix to production. Thanks (yet again!) for the report.

Comment: Great thank you...looks much better.